# If URL contains 6 digit numeric value AND contains .pdf, .doc, .xls etc append the numeric value to a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, append, href

This is an addition to a previous question that I have asked however contains a couple of extra problems that I just cant crack. Again I have searched around and do apologies if this has been answered. I am still learning so please take it easy on me.

The code below rightfully looks for a 6 digit numeric value within a URL and adds the numeric value and 'pdf' as a class to the href.

```js
var regex = /[0-9]{1,6}/;
$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('pdf' + regex.exec($(this).attr("href"))[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/190488/nameoffile.pdf">Link1</a>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/112254/nameoffile.pdf">Link2</a>
```

Problem 1
How can I check for a 6 digit numeric value and if the URL contains any document extension type such as .pdf, .doc, .xls uppercase or lowercase etc? I have tried the below but seem to be having problems with my regex operators. I have also tried to separate the expressions with a 'positive lookahead' assertion but to no avail.

```
var regex = /[0-9]{1,6}/\.(pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|xls|slxs|epub|odp|ods|txt|rtf)$/i;
$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('pdf' + regex.exec($(this).attr("href"))[0]);
});
```

Problem 2
If a page contains a link with a URL that does not qualify (no 6 digit value or document extension), the function stops there and no other link beyond is checked. (example below) How can I make it so the code checks and skips non qualifiers and covers all links that match the regex?

```js
var regex = /[0-9]{1,6}/;
$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('pdf' + regex.exec($(this).attr("href"))[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/190488/nameoffile.pdf">Link1</a><br>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/112254/nameoffile.pdf">Link2</a><br>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/nameoffile.pdf">Link3</a><br>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/145254/nameoffile.pdf">Link4</a><br>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/154254/nameoffile.pdf">Link5</a><br>
```

Thank you once again in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one:

```js
var regex = /\/([0-9]{1,6})\//ig;
$('a').each(function() {
  if ( !this.href.match(regex) ) return;
  $(this).addClass('pdf' + regex.exec($(this).attr("href"))[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/190488/nameoffile.pdf">Link1</a><br>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/112254/nameoffile.pdf">Link2</a><br>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/nameoffile.pdf">Link3</a><br>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/145254/nameoffile.pdf">Link4</a><br>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/154254/nameoffile.pdf">Link5</a><br>
```

**UPDATE: 21/03/2017**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Executes when the HTML document is loaded and ONLY the DOM is ready
    alert("Document is ready");
});

// .load() method deprecated from jQuery 1.8 onward
$(window).on("load", function() {

     // Executes when complete page is fully loaded, including
     // all frames, objects and images
     // This is what you need
     alert("Window is loaded");
});
```

Comment: EfiBN is it possible to load this JQuery after the page and content loads?

Comment: Of course, use it inside $(window).on('load') rether than $(document).ready.
I added Update in the answer for you.

Comment: *rather than (got misspelled)

Comment: Thank you EfBN I will give that a crack

Comment: BentleyO, remember to accept the answer if it helped you, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use addClass directly, with a callback, and then add the class based on the extension, or not at all

```js
$('a').addClass(function() {
    if ( !this.href.match(/[0-9]{1,6}/ ) ) return "";
    var ext = this.href.match(/\.(pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|xls|slxs|epub|odp|ods|txt|rtf)$/i);
    return ext[1] || "";
});
```

```css
.pdf {color: red}
.doc {color: green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/190488/nameoffile.pdf">Link1</a><br>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/112254/nameoffile.pdf">Link2</a><br>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/nameoffile.pdf">Link3</a><br>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/145254/nameoffile.pdf">Link4</a><br>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/154254/nameoffile.pdf">Link5</a><br>
<a href="https://www.pdflinks.com/files/145254/nameoffile.doc">Link4</a><br>
```

Comment: I don't think this one works. Seems to only pull in the file extension as a class not the 6 digit as well.